# Execute a method in a Roslyn CSharpScript and pass parameters without having to pass them as strings or through globals?

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

When a user creates a `C# script` in our product, the only way I have found to send in parameters is through the "globals" parameter.  The calling code is something like this, and it DOES work:

```
public class ArgsWrapper
{        
    public Dictionary<string, object> Args = new Dictionary<string, object>();
}

string code = @"
   return AddStuff((int)Args["x"], (int)Args["y"]);

   private int AddStuff(int x, int y)
   {
      return x + y;
   }";

var script = CSharpScript.Create(code, globalsType: typeof(ArgsWrapper));
args["x"] = 5;
args["y"] = 10;
var res = script.RunAsync(globals: new ArgsWrapper { Args = args }).Result.ReturnValue;
```

But, this is a really awful way to have to pass parameters.  All of the samples and responses to questions like this seem to say "It's easy, just do it like this":

```
res = script.ContinueWith("return AddStuff(5, 10);");
```

This works really great if you are trying to pass primitives that can be converted to strings... but what if you want to pass a DataTable or a List or something like that?

Like I said this works, but it prevents me from asking the user "what is your entry function" and then doing something like using reflection to grab the method and be able to hand across parameters to the method.  I know it may be a pipe dream to think there is a way to do this but I had to ask just in case I am missing something obvious and this can in fact be done.

#endrant... thanks for listening :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another trick is make use of static methods:

```
namespace EduNamespace {
    public class Edu {

        public static dynamic MyObject {get; set;}

        public static void Test()
        {
             // code using MyObjecy
        }
    }
}

Edu.MyObject = new object(); // the object you need

var code = @"Edu.Test();"; 

var response = CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<int>(
    code,
    ScriptOptions.Default
       .WithImports("EduNamespace ")
       .WithReferences(typeof(Edu).Assembly)
);
```